# Windows XP hangs on startup with External Firewire Hard Drive attached

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, firewire

I have a desktop running Windows XP Professional edition that, when an external firewire hard drive is attached, will hang during Windows startup. I see the Windows flag and the scrolling green progress bar during boot, but the computer never advances from here.

The disk is a Western Digital MyBook 500GB firewire drive. When the disk is not attached, the computer boots normally.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if you may have bad firewire connection. Would it be possible for you to connect the drive via USB (may have to use a Firewire->USB adapter). If it worked that way I would imagine you have something wrong with the firewire on your computer (unless you have other firewire devices which work fine other than the hard drive).

I forgot to ask...is there a problem with connecting the drive AFTER startup? If there is no problem that way, you may need to look into your BIOS and see if there is some sort of boot order conflict (unlikely since it is getting partially to windows).

Comment: I'll try this out tonight. What's interesting though is that this is an OEM machine, with the device directly connected to onboard Firewire. But I'll give it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 1394 Net Adapter in Network Connections.